# no keyboard/mouse at login screen

Tags: keyboard, mouse

i am very very new to ubuntu so please give clear answers

following an upgrade to 18.05 i reach the log on screen but no mouse or keyboard working

initially the key board does work and i can get to a screen by pressing esc then shift

```
                gnu grub version 2.02
```

*ubuntu
advanced options for ubuntu
system setup

i did add /bin/bash/ to a command line but not sure i did it correctly

any advice much appreciated

i have read similar posts but get lost

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18.05  (no release occurred in 2018-May as Ubuntu releases show the *year.month* of release),  so check your release details as you could be running something else.  Also are you using Ubuntu Server?  Ubuntu Desktop?  What did you upgrade from?

Comment: many thanks for reply sorry 18.04 and it is running on a laptop